# Find average of doubles in text file with strings and doubles (java)

Tags: java, sum, double, text-files, average

"I have to get the average of doubles from a text file with strings and doubles. With my code, i am getting multiple long doubles, but i only need one double, which should be the average. Please help, I've been trying to fix it for days. Will decimal format or printf be necessary to print the average as well? Here's my code, this is java. "

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        double sum;
        int count;
        sum = 0.0;
        count = 0;

        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("members.txt"));
        while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = readFile.nextLine();
            if (line.length() == 4 && line.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                count++;
                sum += Double.valueOf(line);
                double average= sum/count;
                System.out.println(average);
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: Just divide by 'count' at the end, this is how you make an average not with ((nb1/count)+nb2)/count ...

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need this condition: `line.length() == 4`, also 
why the `for` loop?  
If you want to read 1 text file

```
double sum = 0.0;
int count = 0;
Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("members.txt"));
while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = readFile.nextLine();
    if (line.length() == 4 && line.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
        count++;
        sum += Double.valueOf(line);
    }
}
double average= sum/count;
System.out.println(average);
```

The average is calculated after the loop finishes and not inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move following two lines outside while loop.

```
            double average= sum/count;
            System.out.println(average)
```

Currently , your programs is printing running average after every double it finds in file.